# Equivalent Characterisations of $T_0$ spaces

Tags: general-topology

I once had a script where different equivalent characterisations of the separation axioms for topological spaces where collected, but can not find it anymore. I tried to collect them on my own, but for the $T_0$ property i just found the two eqivalent ones:

i) for two distinct points there always exits an open set containing one but not the other, and

ii) for distinct $x,y$ it is $cl(x) \ne cl(y)$.

I guess there were more listed in the script, can you please help finding the other equivalent characterisations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

- For distinct $x,y$ there is always a closed set containing one but not the other
- For distinct $x,y$ we have $x\notin\text{cl}\{y\}$ or $y\notin\text{cl}\{x\}$
- For distinct $x,y$ the subspace $\{x,y\}$ is not indiscrete.